# Pullback of meromorphic differential forms to blowup

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider $Bl_{(0,0)}\mathbb{A}^2 \stackrel{f}{\to} \mathbb{A}^2$ where $f$ is the natural morphism contracting the exceptional curve to a point. For the pullback of a regular 1-form from $\mathbb{A}^2$ along $f$, one can see in a few different ways that this differential form must be 0 along the exceptional $\mathbb{P}^1$ in the blowup. Either by Hartshorne II.8.11, or by the argument that all tangent vectors that are purely in the  $\mathbb{P}^1$ direction are in the kernel of the differential of $f$.

On the other hand, what happens if I have a meromorphic differential form? Say, one with a denominator that vanishes along some proper subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^2$ containing $(0,0)$. I think there ought to be some sort of calculus argument here which says something different will happen, but I'm fairly confused about this right now. Any advice or answers would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you calculated? Have you calculated the pull back of $dx/x, dx/y$, where $x,y$ are coordinates?

Comment: I'm having trouble calculating anything. Or at least I'm unsure about what's actually happening. I think meromorphic differentials should probably form a constant sheaf on $A^2$, and the pullback of a constant sheaf is again a constant sheaf, so I should get $dx/x$ and $dx/y$. When I restrict these to $P^1$, I don't know what should happen. I get the feeling I should probably use the defining equations of the blowup, but I'm still fairly lost. (How do you use the defining equation $xv=yu$ for either of those? What happens if you have something like $fdx/(x^2+y^2)$?)

Comment: The blow up can be covered by two open sets which are affine planes. Make the calculations using those.